# Basemap not showing up when saving Shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, basemap

I am very much a beginner here.

I am trying to create a Shapefile to send to an agency to indicate where I will be conducting field work. I am using OCM Landscape Basemap, and I just have a few points added as Shapefile layers to indicate where my field sites are. However, when I save and try to open the Shapefile, there is no Basemap, and all I see are my little dots. How do I save a map with my field sites (as my little dots) and the Basemap in the Shapefile format?

Answer (score 3):

A basemap is a raster and cannot be saved as a SHP file which is a vector format. Probably the best way is to send a map in an image format (ie png). See the QGIS [help.](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_output.html)

Comment: Thank you! Although they specifically want a SHP file :(